# Automapper issue: Unmapped members were found after version upgrade and .Net Upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mapping, automapper, .net-6.0

I am upgrading the .Net Core Version to .Net 6.0 and while doing the same I upgraded the relevant packages including Automapper from ver 9.0 to 12.0.

But after upgrading when I run the application I get following error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
> Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver or modify the source/destination type...

Earlier it was all working fine.
Things I have tried so far:
I tried to add the properties in both source and destination, as I got in exception message but it just keeps looping me around and I keep adding more and more properties as properties are interdependent.

Please help me with this issue with something simple which can save both time and effort and can be a quick smart solution.

Thanks

Comment: You either isolate the issue to a few lines of code or you don't upgrade. `exception.ToString()` is telling you exactly what's wrong with your mappings.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thank you for your comment buddy, I want to understand two things: 1. why it was not happening earlier (before upgrade) as the properties/models are the same, there is no change in them?
2. I have added properties in dto and model as per all the recommendations in the exception message but this keeps bringing new dependencies and the number of properties is huge, also in the end I am stuck with 2 properties in a deadlock kind of situation.

Please guide me further on this. thanks!

Comment: That's not helpful. You have to isolate the issue to smth that makes sense.

Comment: Could you provide the minimal codes that could reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1):

I usually have a unit test to test my configuration using `AssertConfigurationIsValid` - that can give you more information.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html?highlight=AssertConfigurationIsValid%20